# I'm coding a discord bot using discord.js and I'm working on a suggestion command

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm currently trying to get the bot to send a filler message to the channel I eventually want the suggestions to go to and have tried multiple methods to do so, but keep getting errors. I'm sure the solution is very simple, and any help is much appreciated.

suggest.js

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'suggest',
    aliases: ['suggestion'],
    description: 'Sends a suggestion to the <#700591796119535657> channel.',
    usage: '<your suggestion>',
    cooldown: 1,
    execute(message, args) {
        const Discord = require('discord.js');
        const client = new Discord.Client();
        const channel = client.channels.cache.get('701087240729657457');
        channel.send('test');
    },
};
```

error message in console upon running .suggest

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'send' of undefined
    at Object.execute (/home/shares/public/RetroCraft/commands/suggest.js:11:11)
    at Client.<anonymous> (/home/shares/public/RetroCraft/index.js:69:11)
    at Client.emit (events.js:310:20)
    at MessageCreateAction.handle (/home/shares/public/RetroCraft/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/actions/MessageCreate.js:31:14)
    at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] (/home/shares/public/RetroCraft/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/handlers/MESSAGE_CREATE.js:4:32)
    at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (/home/shares/public/RetroCraft/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketManager.js:386:31)
    at WebSocketShard.onPacket (/home/shares/public/RetroCraft/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketShard.js:436:22)
    at WebSocketShard.onMessage (/home/shares/public/RetroCraft/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketShard.js:293:10)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (/home/shares/public/RetroCraft/node_modules/ws/lib/event-target.js:120:16)
    at WebSocket.emit (events.js:310:20)
```

index.js

```
const fs = require('fs');
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const { prefix, token } = require('./config.json');

const cooldowns = new Discord.Collection();
const client = new Discord.Client();
client.commands = new Discord.Collection();

const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));

for (const file of commandFiles) {
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);

    // set a new item in the Collection
    // with the key as the command name and the value as the exported module
    client.commands.set(command.name, command);
}

client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Ready!');
    client.user.setActivity('RetroCraft', { type: 'WATCHING' });
});

client.on('message', message => {
    if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
    const commandName = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    const command = client.commands.get(commandName)
        || client.commands.find(cmd => cmd.aliases && cmd.aliases.includes(commandName));

    if (!command) return;

    if (command.guildOnly && message.channel.type !== 'text') {
        return message.reply('I can\'t execute that command inside DMs!');
    }

    if (command.args && !args.length) {
        let reply = `You didn't provide any arguments, ${message.author}!`;

        if (command.usage) {
            reply += `\nThe proper usage would be: \`${prefix}${command.name} ${command.usage}\``;
        }

        return message.channel.send(reply);
    }
    if (!cooldowns.has(command.name)) {
        cooldowns.set(command.name, new Discord.Collection());
    }

    const now = Date.now();
    const timestamps = cooldowns.get(command.name);
    const cooldownAmount = (command.cooldown || 3) * 1000;

    if (timestamps.has(message.author.id)) {
        const expirationTime = timestamps.get(message.author.id) + cooldownAmount;

        if (now < expirationTime) {
            const timeLeft = (expirationTime - now) / 1000;
            return message.reply(`please wait ${timeLeft.toFixed(1)} more second(s) before reusing the \`${command.name}\` command.`);
        }
    }

    timestamps.set(message.author.id, now);
    setTimeout(() => timestamps.delete(message.author.id), cooldownAmount);

    try {
        command.execute(message, args);
    }
    catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        message.reply('there was an error trying to execute that command!');
    }
});

client.login(token);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a really easy fix. Just change the `channel.send` to `message.channel.send` and that should work. Tell me if you get any errors and I'll try to help :)

Comment: The message.channel.send sends the reply to the same channel I sent the command, not the channel I want the messages to go to.

Comment: Try: ` const channel = client.channels.cache.find('name', channelName) channel.send('test') `

Comment: ```
  const channel = client.channels.cache.find('staff-chat', channelName);

  channel.send('test');
```
Not sure if this is what you meant, but I get channelName is undefined and I'm not sure how to define it.

Comment: Sorry, in channelName, insert the channel name. for the 'name', you want to just leave it as it is. So:
` const channel = client.channels.cache.find('name', staff-chat); channel.send('test')`
Hope this works

Comment: `const channel = client.channels.cache.find('name', staff-chat); channel.send('test');`
This is what I used and I didn't think it would work because now I'm getting errors that neither "staff" nor "chat" are defined. Wouldn't inputting channel names or anything of the sore always require quotes? I also tried it with quotes and switching it around a bunch of different ways but couldn't get that to work either. I'm going to put my index.js code in my original post if that helps.

Comment: Hm... you're right. I did a little tweak and it should work now.
`message.guild.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.name === "channel-name")`
Hope this works for you!

Comment: Tysm that worked perfectly, I'll go ahead and mark your answer as correct. Thanks for the help!

Comment: No problem, glad to help!